# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable ...want only string values in List

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, plotly-dash

I'm getting the following error

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

and want to only string from List, is it possible to get only string in List?

Here is my **init.py**

```
def get_fx_pairs(pairs_str: List[str]) -> List[FXPair]:
    from investapp.models.fxpairs import FXPair
    pairs: List[FXPair] = []
    print("pairs_str::",pairs_str)
    for pair_str in pairs_str:
      if (pair_str):
        try: 
          pair = FXPair.query.filter_by(pair=pairs_str).one()
        except NoResultFound:
          pair = FXPair(pairs_str)
          db.session.add(pair)
          db.session.commit()
          db.session.flush()
   pairs.append(pair)
return pairs
```

Comment: error :    for pair_str in pairs_str:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

There are too many approach for doing this. one of them is to check the class of array item like this--

```
def get_fx_pairs(pairs_str: List[str]) -> List[FXPair]:
    if not isinstance(pair_str,list):
       return
    from investapp.models.fxpairs import FXPair
    pairs: List[FXPair] = []
    print("pairs_str::",pairs_str)
    for pair_str in pairs_str:
        if pair_str and isinstance(pair_str,str):
            try: 
                pair = FXPair.query.filter_by(pair=pairs_str).one()
            except NoResultFound:
                pair = FXPair(pairs_str)
                db.session.add(pair)
                db.session.commit()
                db.session.flush()
            pairs.append(pair)
    return pairs
```

Comment: make sure to only append in pairs array if you find an item in your db!! and if you are getting error in line  for pair_str in pairs_str: saying as you mentioned above then you are not passing array in function call instead you are passing a int.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ...yes i am getting that in ..for pair_str in pairs_str:...this line...is there any solution for i will get only str values in ..pairs_str: List[str]

Comment: i just want to get str values in list from front end

Comment: hey I don't think python provide strong type checking like C it would be better you check parameter type beforehand. I'm editing my answer please have a look.